# Split String at every dot except when some word appears

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, split

I'm really new into regex and currently getting some trouble to solve a problem. I will appreciate any help :)

Using ruby 2.4.2

The problem: Split a string at every dot, except when the asd word is after the dot

```
String: str = "qwer.qwer.asd"
Code: str.split(/\./)
Output: ["qwer", "qwer", "asd"]

The output should be: ["qwer", "qwer.asd"]
```

Comment: You can use `str.split(/\.(?!asd)/)`

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! Thank you @anubhava

Comment: @anubhava, close, but you really need the word break that Wiktor includes (so, for example, `"asdcookie"` is not matched.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
str.split(/\.(?!asd\b)/)
```

The `\.(?!asd\b)` pattern matches any dot that is not followed with `asd` followed with a word boundary. The `(?!asd\b)` is a *negative lookahead* that fails the match if the lookahead pattern finds a match immediately to the right of the current location.

In case the "word" ends with a period or end of string, use

```
str.split(/\.(?!asd(?:\.|\z))/)
```

where `(?:\.|\z)` is a non-capturing group matching either a dot (`\.`) or (`|`) end of string (`\z`).

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/V5Q8E1) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rUUM2O/1).